# Is something wrong with the method?

Tags: java

So that's my method and i got Main class from my teacher that uses this method and it should return only 1 Suspect but it returns the same one for 8 times or something i am really close on my deadline please help

```html
public ArrayList<Suspect> getCommonPartners(Suspect aSuspect) {
ArrayList<Suspect> commonpartners = new ArrayList<>() ;
    for(Suspect s: partners) {
        for(Suspect sus: aSuspect.getPartners()) {
            if(s.getCodename().equals(sus.getCodename())) {
                commonpartners.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return (commonpartners);
}
```

Comment: What is `partners`? What does `getpartners` return?

Comment: Is `partners` a class attribute ? if yes ,can you show us the full class ?

Comment: partners is an arraylist with every partner of each suspect

Comment: public void addPartner(Suspect aSuspect) {
 if(partners.size()<1) {
  partners.add(aSuspect);
 }else {
 
 for(Suspect s : partners) {
  if(s.getName().equals(aSuspect.getName()) && s.getCodename().equals(aSuspect.getCodename())) {
   System.out.println("Partner already exists in Suspect's list") ;
   break ;
 } 
}
 partners.add(aSuspect) ;
 }

Comment: that's how i add partners

Comment: This code looks ok to me. It finds common elements of `this.partners` and `aSuspect.partners` based on their codename. Please verify that the 2 input lists dont contain duplicate entries.

Comment: Can you put that in the question itself? It's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: @VasilisTsonis Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I think this is a useful question, just please edit the title

Answer (score 2):

Where is 'partners' coming from? You're running a for loop on it. Did you mean aSuspect?

If you are getting multiple of the same value. Do a check on the arraylist before adding it.

```
public ArrayList<Suspect> getCommonPartners(Suspect aSuspect) {
ArrayList<Suspect> commonpartners = new ArrayList<>() ;
    for(Suspect s: partners) {
        for(Suspect sus: aSuspect.getPartners()) {
            if(s.getCodename().equals(sus.getCodename())) {
                if(!commonpartners.contains(s)) {
                    commonpartners.add(s);
                  }
            }
        }
    }
    return (commonpartners);
}
```

Comment: @YasserCHENIK what is the purpose of your comment?

Comment: Thanks for the help can you help me find what was i doin wrong?